# Missing DLC bug

Tags: saints-row-iv

I recently purchased the season pass and super saints outfit pack, but I'm not seeing either of them in-game. I've seen people on the steam forums talking about missing DLC bugs but does anyone know how to fix this issue?

How can I first check to see if the DLC is actually installed or not, and if it is installed how can I be sure it is "active" in the game when I go to play it?

Comment: Have you actually progressed in the game? I don't know about the outfit packs, but the Explosive Pack & Season Pass content isn't available until you get several missions into the plot.

Comment: I'm most interested in the outfits not showing up. I could understand missions not being available instantly, but I want to look like a Superhero already!

Comment: If you are using Steam you can check isntalled DLCs by right clicking on the game in your library.